# After Update Trigger and wrong values

Tags: apex, trigger, map, after-trigger

I have a Trigger and Trigger Helper.

- `Opportunity` is a parent for `CompanyOrder__c`.
- One `Opportunity` can have many `CompanyOrder__c` records with uncrossed Start- and End Dates.
- `CompanyOrder__c` is a parent for `Supply__c`.
- Each `CompanyOrder__c` can haveonly 1 `Supply__c`.
- If we have 1 `Opportunity` with `CompanyOrder1` and `CompanyOrder2` where `CompanyOrder1.EndDate__c == CompanyOrder2.StartDate__c`, the `Supply__c` record of `CompanyOrder1` should get a `Tools__c` value from `CompanyOrder2.OrdersTools__c`.

Everything works, but not always. When I get many records, Supplies can be with wrong `Tools__c` values.

Trigger:

```
if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate) {
    CleaningsTriggerHelper.updateSupplies(Trigger.new);  
}
```

Helper:

```
public static void updateSupplies(List<CompanyOrder__c> createdCompanyOrders){
    Map<Id, Supply__c> mapSuppliesToConnect = new Map<Id, Supply__c>();
    Map<Id, Supply__c> mapSuppliesToUpdate = new Map<Id, Supply__c>();
    List<Id> oppIds = new List<Id>();
    List<Date> compOStartDate = new List<Date>();

    for(CompanyOrder__c compOToCheck : createdCompanyOrders){
        oppIds.add(compOToCheck.Opportunity__c);
        if(compOToCheck.StartDate__c != null){ 
            compOStartDate.add(Date.newinstance(compOToCheck.StartDate__c.year(), compOToCheck.StartDate__c.month(), compOToCheck.StartDate__c.day()));
        }
    }

    List<Supply__c> actualSupplies = [SELECT EndDate__c, CompanyOrder__r.Opportunity__c, Tools__c FROM Supply__c
    WHERE CompanyOrder__r.Opportunity__c IN : oppIds AND DAY_ONLY(EndDate__c) IN : compOStartDate
    AND DAY_ONLY(EndDate__c) >= : Date.TODAY()];

    if(actualSupplies.size() > 0){
        for(Supply__c sup : actualSupplies){
            mapSuppliesToConnect.put(sup.CompanyOrder__r.Opportunity__c, sup);
        }
    }

    if(!mapSuppliesToConnect.isEmpty()){
        for(CompanyOrder__c compO : createdCompanyOrders){
            Id opportunityId = compO.Opportunity__c;
            Supply__c supplyForUpd = mapSuppliesToConnect.get(opportunityId);

            if(supplyForUpd != null){
                if(compO.OrdersTools__c > 0){
                    mapSuppliesToConnect.get(opportunityId).Tools__c = String.valueOf(compO.OrdersTools__c);
                } else{
                    mapSuppliesToConnect.get(opportunityId).Tools__c = '';
                }
                mapSuppliesToUpdate.put(supplyForUpd.Id, supplyForUpd);
            }
        }
    }

    if(mapSuppliesToUpdate.size() > 0){
        update mapSuppliesToUpdate.values();
    }
}
```

**Updated:** I found the problem. I'm getting wrong values because of the updating only the last one element in the map. How can I fix it?

Comment: Try to debug the code.

Comment: Updated: I found the problem. I'm getting wrong values because of the updating only the last one element in the map.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anyplace in your code where you're validating that the Dates of all related `CompanyOrder__c` have StartDates and EndDates that do not overlap with one another. That would require a query for all `CompanyOrder__c`'s related to the parent `Opportunity`, then iterating through the `StartDates` and `EndDates` since not all instances of them will necessarily be included in this instance of the trigger execution. This could easily account for the discrepancies you're seeing.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. These dates never overlap. It's a rule.

Comment: Updated: I found the problem. I'm getting wrong values because of the updating only the last one element in the map.